# radgridview change color of text between {}

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, telerik

I am using a RadGridView to display some string data in a column. I am using databinding. Some of my text strings have portions of the text encased with {} and I would like to display this text in a different color.

From looking around on the net I have found that I can change text color of text in a text block but Im having trouble applying this to a databound datagrid column.

Could anyone advise if this is possible.

---EDIT---

Heres xaml where I define datacolumn:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colMasterValue" Header="Localise - Master Value" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MasterValue}" ShowDistinctFilters="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Heres the display:
[image]

So what I want is {Customer.Panel.field} to appear in a different color.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the next solution.

1. Will use a custom TextBlock that can separate regular character and the '{' or '}'.
2. Let's add the replace mechanism that can replace the original text with decorated text. Where all text except the '{' or '}' colored in some way.

**Here is the xaml code:**

```
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text}"
                                        Header="HeaderName"
                                        IsFilterable="False" IsReorderable="False">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="flowConfiguration:SomeDataType">
                        <modules:MyTextBlock Text="{Binding Text, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**Here is the MyTextBlock code**

```
public class MyTextBlock:TextBlock
{
    private DependencyPropertyDescriptor _descriptor;
    private bool _isUpdating;

    public MyTextBlock()
    {
        this.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        _descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
        _descriptor.AddValueChanged(this, OnValueChanged);
    }


    private void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if(_isUpdating) return;
        _isUpdating = true;
        var text = Text;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;

        Inlines.Clear();
        UpdateInlines(text);
        _isUpdating = false;
    }

    private void UpdateInlines(string text)
    {
        //text = @"{Customer.Panel.field}";
        var runs = new List<Run>();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var current in text)
        {
            if (current.Equals('}') || current.Equals('{'))
            {
                if (sb.Length == 0)
                {
                    runs.Add(new Run
                    {
                        Text = current.ToString()
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    runs.Add(new Run
                    {
                        Text = sb.ToString(),
                        Foreground = Brushes.Red
                    });
                    runs.Add(new Run
                    {
                        Text = current.ToString()
                    });
                    sb.Clear();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(current);
            }
        }
        if(sb.Length > 0)
            runs.Add(new Run{Text = sb.ToString(), Foreground = Brushes.Red});
        runs.ForEach(run => 
            Inlines.Add(run));
    }


    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        this.Unloaded -= OnUnloaded;
        _descriptor.RemoveValueChanged(this, OnValueChanged);
    }


}
```

regards.